# Pythonのsmtplibでメールを送信する際に、ログをターミナルに出力したい

Tags: python, smtplib

複数の人にメールを自動送信するためのプログラムを書いています。

#### 概要

- Python の smtplib モジュールを使用し、複数の宛先にメールを自動送信するコードを作成。
- 宛先のメールアドレスリスト一覧が記載されたcsvファイルを読み込み、一行ずつループ処理で、message['To']に指定し、送信。
- 何度か送信テストを実施して、送信自体は成功している。

#### 達成したいこと

メールが正常に送信できたのか、それとも何かエラーが起き、送信が正常に完了しなかったか、を1通ごとに把握したい。以下のようなイメージで、ターミナルにログを出力したい。

```
2021-09-07 11:56:23 Email to example@gmail.com status: success
2021-09-07 11:56:29 Email to error@gmail.com status: failure
```

#### 試したこと

Pythonのドキュメントを調べ、`SMTP.set_debuglevel()` というものがあることを知り、コードに組み込んだ。

#### 今悩んでいること

`SMTP.set_debuglevel()` の出力内容が理解できず、どのようにすれば、メール送信の成功、不成功、といった情報を、1通ごとに全て出力できるのか、わからない。

```
message = EmailMessage()
message['Subject'] = 'タイトル'
message['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
      smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
      for row in reader:
        message['To'] = row[0]
        message.set_content('メッセージ本文')        
        smtp.send_message(message)
        smtp.set_debuglevel(True)
```

ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: ログといっても SMTP サーバとのやり取りでエラーが発生したかどうかしか検出できませんが、それでもよろしいですか？ Deliver status(配送状況)に関しては、その時点では分かりません(SMTP サーバに一旦キューイングされてから配送されるためです)。

Comment: 質問をする際は「作りたいものがある」だと範囲が広すぎるので、実際に試して躓いた部分に的を絞り込んだほうが回答も付きやすいと思います。今回であればまず `SMTP.set_debuglevel()` の結果の読み方が分からない、あたりではないでしょうか。

Comment: @metropolis ご教示ありがとうございます。そうしますと、例えばメールアドレスの入力ミスがあった場合は、送信元アドレスへMail Delivery Subsystemより、Delivery Status Notification (Failure)という通知がきますが、相手先の受信サーバへメールを届けようとした際に何かエラーが発生したかどうかは、このNotificationのみによって感知できるということでしょうか？

Comment: @cubick なるほど、質問の仕方が重要なんですね。勉強になります。

Comment: @Shin はい、その通りです。

Comment: @metropolis わかりました。コメントにいただいた、SMTPとのやりとりのエラー検知方法について、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shin さん:

> 例えばメールアドレスの入力ミスがあった場合は、送信元アドレスへMail Delivery Subsystemより、Delivery Status Notification (Failure)という通知がきますが、相手先の受信サーバへメールを届けようとした際に何かエラーが発生したかどうかは、このNotificationのみによって感知できるということでしょうか？

私:

> はい、その通りです。

`smtp.send_message()` を実行する際に発生する可能性のある `smtplib.SMTPException` を例外処理(`try ~ except`)で検出します。

```py
import sys
from datetime import datetime

message = EmailMessage()
message['Subject'] = 'タイトル'
message['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
# 同じメッセージ本文であればここで定義してもよいはず
message.set_content('メッセージ本文')

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
      #smtp.set_debuglevel(True)
      smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
      for row in reader:
        message['To'] = row[0]

        status = 'success'
        try:
            smtp.send_message(message)
        except smtplib.SMTPException:
            status = 'failure'
        finally:
            now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
            print(f'{now} Email to {message["To"]} status: {status}', file=sys.stderr)
        del message['To']
```

例えば質問文にある `error@gmail.com` に送信してみると、

> `2021/09/09 09:39:05 Email to error@gmail.com status: success`

と表示されますが、この後に `Mail From`(もしくは `Return-Path`)に設定したメールアドレスに以下の様なメールが届きます。

> Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
> Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
>
> ** アドレス不明 **
>
> アドレスが見つからなかったか、メールを受信できないアドレスであるため、メールは error@gmail.com に配信されませんでした。
>
> 詳細: https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser
>
> 応答:
>
> 550 5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary spaces. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser

`error@gmail.com` に送信した場合の SMTP サーバとのやり取りは以下になります(必要な部分だけを抜き出して記載しています)。

```c
send: mail FROM:<...> size=212
reply: 250 2.1.0 OK
send: rcpt TO:<error@gmail.com>
reply: 250 2.1.5 OK
send: data
reply: 354 Go ahead
send: Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8" ...
reply: 250 2.0.0 OK  1631147944

# これは前述の Python スクリプトが表示しています
2021/09/09 09:39:05 Email to error@gmail.com status: success

send: QUIT
reply: 221 2.0.0 closing connection
```

それでは `SMTPException` が発生するのはどの様な場合かと言えば、例えばメールアドレスが非正規な形式になっている場合です。一例としてドメイン名を指定しないアドレス宛に送信してみます。

メールアドレス `error` 宛に送信

```c
send: mail FROM:<...> size=202
reply: 250 2.1.0 OK
send: rcpt TO:<error>
reply: 553 5.1.3 The recipient address <error> is not a valid RFC-5321 address.
send: rset
reply: 250 2.1.5 Flushed

2021/09/09 09:56:46 Email to error status: failure

send: QUIT
reply: 221 2.0.0 closing connection
```

まぁ、後から届く `Delivery Status Notification (Failure)` のメールを自動的にチェックして…などという事も考えられなくはないですが、面倒ではありますね。。。

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。非正規なemailでの"Failure"出力まで確認できました。とりあえずはこちらと、送信元に届くDelivery Status Notificationを両方チェックして未達確認としたいと思います。助かりました。